# Apply function to multiple columns with multiple columns

Tags: r

In the data below, there are values for `2005`and `2006`. Each year has 2 columns as `h1`and `h24`. Function `myfun` is using `h1`to aggregate hourly data to 6, 12  and 24 hourly data as `h6`,`h12` and `h24` and finding means of them as `mean1`, `mean6`, `mean12` and `mean24` for each year separately and listing them.

**Head of the data:**

```
    X2005.h1  X2005.h24   X2006.h1 X2006.h24
1        0       0.0        0       0.0
2        0       0.0        0       8.6
3        0       3.4        0      11.2
4        0      21.4        0       8.4
5        0       1.8        0       0.0
6        0       1.4        0       0.0
```

**And my whole data is:**

```
myd<-structure(list(X2005.h1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.6, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.8, 
1.8, 1.2, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.2, 1.4, 1, 1.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 
1.6, 0.4, 0, 0.4, 1.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 1.2, 1.6, 2.2, 1.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 
0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.4, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 
0, 1.2, 4, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 1.4, 
0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.2, 1.2, 1, 1.8, 2, 1.8, 0.4, 0.6, 1.2, 1.8, 1.4, 1.2, 
0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 1.6, 1.6, 1.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 
0.6, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.2, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2006.h1 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4.8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 6.6, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 1.4, 0, 1.2, 0, 0.2, 
0, 0.2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.8, 5.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 
3.8, 0.2, 1.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.2, 
0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 2.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 1.6, 0.2, 2, 0, 1.2, 
4.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.8, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 2, 1, 0.8, 
0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 
4, 2, 0.8, 2.6, 1.4, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.2, 0.8, 1.6, 1.8, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.6, 1.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 1.2, 1.2, 0.8, 1, 2.2, 3.4, 
2.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 3.6, 3, 1.8, 3.2, 1.8, 1, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 1, 
0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.6, 3.8, 0.2, 0.4, 
0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 
0, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 
1, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 1.4, 2.2, 0, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 0, 
1.2, 1.6, 0.6, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 
0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 1.2, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 
0.8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2005.h24 = c(0, 0, 3.4, 21.4, 1.8, 1.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.6, 1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 7, 6.4, 
21.8, 3.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 11.2, 0), X2006.h24 = c(0, 8.6, 11.2, 8.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.8, 7.6, 1.2, 10.2, 7, 0, 0, 1.6, 7.6, 23.6, 
3.2, 0, 9, 31.4, 10, 2.2, 1.6, 0, 4.8, 10, 1.2, 4.6)), .Names = c("X2005.h1", 
"X2006.h1", "X2005.h24", "X2006.h24"))
```

**The function:**

```
myfun<- function(x) {

  y<-as.matrix(sapply(x, as.numeric)) 
  #Aggregating hourly (h1) data to 6,12 hourly data      
  h<-sapply(c(1, 6, 12), function(hrs) colSums(matrix(y, ncol=length(x)/hrs)))
  hours<-sapply(list(h[[1]], h[[2]], h[[3]]), function(qq) list(qq))
  names(hours)<-c("h1", "h6", "h12")
  #Calculating means of 1, 6, 12 hourly data      
  means<-sapply(list(hours[[1]], hours[[2]], hours[[3]]), function(ss) mean(ss, na.rm = T))
  #means of 1, 6, 12 hourly data 
  mean1<-means[[1]]
  mean6<-means[[2]]
  mean12<-means[[3]]
  mean24<- means[[4]]   
  meanlist<-list(mean1, mean6, mean12, mean24)
  names(meanlist) <- c("mean1", "mean6", "mean12", "mean24")
  return(meanlist)
    }
```

***What I want is:***

As aformentioned before, 6-12-24 hourly values are obtained with aggregation of hourly data `h1` as `h6`,`h12` and `h24`. `mean1`, `mean6`, `mean12` and `mean24` are calculating in loop with `lapply` function for each year.

Means `mean1`, `mean6`, `mean12` are okey. But to obtain `mean24`, I want to use `h24` data (x2005.h24, x2006.h24,...) instead of aggregated `h24` data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The data you provided is not tabular (no rows or columns), it's a list of 4 elements `X2005.h1`, `X2005.h24`,  `X2006.h1`, and `X2006.h24`, the first two are of length 744, and the later two are of length 31, is this one month of data?  if not then what do you mean by hourly data? and with the sample data you provided, how do expect the output to look like?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHnaQ.png The output will be like that. Yes it is monthly data. length 31 data is daily, 744 is hourly data. But to find means of 1-6-12 hourly data, I will use only 744-length data, but to find mean of 24 hourly data, I will use  daily (31-length) data

Comment: Why not do the same for the mean of 24h?

Comment: The trouble occured because of this. Data is obtained from a meteorology station and for a month; sums of hourly data is not equal to sum of daily data generally. And the real daily data is the true one. So I decided to obtain mean of main daily data

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I'm not used to analysing data represented in lists, usually data.frames or time series, this doesn't seem very efficient, but since I don't have any better suggestion, here's one way this could be done, create a new list which includes the data you want (every six and 12 hours), and then apply the mean on each element

```
# list with 1h data
l1 <- myd[grepl('h1', names(myd))]

# list with 6h and 12h data
l6_12 <- names(myd)[grepl('h1', names(myd))] %>% 
  lapply(function(x) {
    setNames(lapply(c(6,12), 
                    function(h) rowSums(matrix(myd[[x]], ncol = h))), 
             c(gsub('h1', 'h6', x), gsub('h1', 'h12', x)))
  }) %>% 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE)

# list with 24h data
l24 <- myd[grepl('h24', names(myd))]

# combine all three together and then take the mean of each element (in this case 8 elements in total)
c(l1, l6_12, l24) %>% lapply(mean)
```